# If we use a perceptron with a non-monotonic activation function, can it solve the XOR problem?

Tags: neural-networks, activation-functions, perceptron, xor-problem

I found several papers about how to build a perceptron able to solve the XOR problem. The papers describe a solution where the heaviside step function is replaced by a non-monotonic activation function. Here are the papers:

- [Single Layer Neural Network Solution for XOR Problem](http://hsmazumdar.net/single_layer_neural_net.htm)
- [Solving the XOR and parity N problems using a single universal binary neuron](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227309651_Solving_the_XOR_and_parity_Nproblems_using_a_single_univers)

I also found [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30412427/3924118) on Stackoverflow.

Can we really solve the XOR problem with a simple perceptron?

The use of a non-monotonic activation function is not really common, so I don't really know. Papers about this idea are scarce. Generally, the main solution is to build a multilayer perceptron.